# Get service in animation definition file

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an element on my homepage whose CSS transform angle is dynamically calculated based on the viewport dimensions. These calculations are done in a separate service.

The element is also part of my routing animations, for which I have a separate definition file. I would like to use the calculated angle in these animation definitions, but I don't know how I would achieve this, since there's no constructor to inject the service with.

Is there a way to access a service from an animation definition file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I correctly understand your question, (let me know if I didn't).
I don't think there's a way to achieve this in the way you suggested, what you can do are (I'm using width and height instead of transform angle for the simplicity):

## Option 1.

I believe one approach your question is using [Reusable animations](https://angular.io/guide/reusable-animations), use it as following:

**animation.ts**

```
export const animation = trigger('animation', [
  transition('* <=> *', [
    query('.element', style({ height: '{{height}}', width: '{{width}}' })),
]),
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  animations: [animation]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private elementSize: ElementSizeService) { }

  height: string;
  width: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.elementSize.getSize$.subscribe((x: { height: string, width: string }) => {
      this.height = this.height;
      this.width = this.width;
    })
  }

  public prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
    const state = outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData['state'];
    return { value : state ? state : null, params: { width: this.width, height: this.height } };
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div [@animation]="prepareRoute(o)">
  <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

## Option 2.

Another aproach is using [AnimationBuilder](https://angular.io/api/animations/AnimationBuilder),

> **AnimationBuilder** - An injectable service that produces an animation sequence programmatically within an Angular component or directive. Provided by the BrowserAnimationsModule or NoopAnimationsModule.

Instead of using triggers and states, you could use the AnimationBuilder, which simplifies things and I belived it's best fitted for situations like these, the end result of the animation is kept.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AnimationBuilder, animate, style } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('element') element: ElementRef;
  animationPlayer: any;
  height: string;
  width: string;

  constructor(private animBuilder: AnimationBuilder, private elementSize: ElementSizeService) {
    this.elementSize.getSize$.subscribe((x: { height: string, width: string }) => {
      this.height = this.height;
      this.width = this.width;
    })
  }

  makeAnimation() {
    const animation = this.animBuilder.build([
      animate(1000, style({
        width: this.width,
        height: this.height,
      }))
    ]);

    this.animationPlayer = animation.create(this.element.nativeElement);
    this.animationPlayer.onDone((x) => { });
    this.animationPlayer.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the first option could work. However, in my prepareRoute function, I also return the 'state' parameter retrieved from the route definitions like this: `return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData['state']`

How would I combine this with the params you mentioned?

Comment: Yes! That did the trick! I have also discovered a third option, which is more of a workaround: in the animation definition you can set your styles equal to a CSS variable. This variable can then be updated continuously within your component. When the animation is fired, it uses the most up to date value of the variable. However, since CSS variables are a relatively new addition, backwards compatibility  might be less than your solutions.